# How to prove that: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n!}\int_0^ne^{-t}t^n\,dt.=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to Show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n!}\int_0^ne^{-t}t^n\,dt=\frac12.$$

I tried to squeeze the sequence as follows

$$\frac{n^{n}(1-e^{-n})}{n!}= \frac1{n!}\int_0^ne^{-t}n^n\,dt\ge \frac1{n!}\int_0^ne^{-t}t^n\,dt \ge \frac1{n!}\int_0^ne^{-n}t^n\,dt =\frac{n^{n+1}e^{-n}}{(n+1)!} .$$

Then what next? any idea?

Comment: $$\dfrac{d(e^{-t}t^n)}{dt}=-e^{-t}t^n-ne^{-t}t^{n-1}$$

If $I_m=\int e^{-t}t^m\ dx,$

$$I_n+nI_{n-1}=-e^{-t}t^n$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I think you got the minus sign in front of the second term in the differentiation wrong. (Also, I'm curious about where Guy Fsone found this exercise.)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2558208/using-the-central-limit-theorem-to-show-lim-n-to-infty-frac1n-1-i/2558338#2558338

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffe]{\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{{1 \over n!}\int_{0}^{n}\expo{-t}t^{n}\,\dd t}}}  =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
{1 \over n!}\int_{0}^{n}\expo{-\pars{n - t}}\pars{n - t}^{n}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
{\expo{-n}n^{n} \over n!}\int_{0}^{n}\expo{t}\pars{1 - {t \over n}}^{n}\,\dd t} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
{\expo{-n}n^{n} \over n!}\int_{0}^{n}
\exp\pars{t + n\ln\pars{1 - {t \over n}}}\,\dd t}
\end{align}

> At this point, I'll use the
>   [Laplace Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method):

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffe]{\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{{1 \over n!}\int_{0}^{n}\expo{-t}t^{n}\,\dd t}}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
{\expo{-n}n^{n} \over n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-\,{t^{2} \over 2n}}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
{\expo{-n}n^{n} \over n!}\,\pars{\root{\pi \over 2}\,n^{1/2}}} =
{\root{2\pi} \over 2}\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{%
{\expo{-n}n^{n + 1/2} \over n!}}
\\[5mm] & =
{\root{2\pi} \over 2}\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{%
{\expo{-n}n^{n + 1/2} \over \root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\expo{-n}}}\qquad
\pars{~n!\!-\!Stirling\ Asymptotic\ Expansion ~}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{1 \over 2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

We first give the integral in terms of [Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and [Incomplete Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) function:
\begin{align}
\int^{n}_0 t^n e^{-t}\,dt =\int^{\infty}_0 t^n e^{-t}\,dt -\int^\infty_n t^n e^{-t}\,dt = \Gamma(n+1)-\Gamma(n+1,n) = n!-\Gamma(n+1,n)
\end{align}
Hence:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n!}\int^{n}_0 t^n e^{-t}\,dt=1-\frac{\Gamma(n+1,n)}{n!}
\end{align}
Now we use the result found in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2514305) (it is after edit II before the conclusion), namely:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+1,n)}{n!} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
And finally we get:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\int^{n}_0 t^n e^{-t}\,dt = 1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

---

**Edit (Alternative approach)**.

I added an extra approach that relies on the CLT. First let's split up the integral:
\begin{align}
\int^n_0 t^ne^{-t}\,dt =\int^{n+1}_0 t^ne^{-t}\,dt - \int^{n+1}_n t^ne^{-t}\,dt
\end{align}
Then we know from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2558338) the following:
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\int^{n+1}_0 t^ne^{-t}\,dt = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int^{n}_0 t^{n-1}e^{-t}\,dt  =\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
For the other part, note that:
\begin{align}
0\leq \frac{1}{n!}\int^{n+1}_n t^n e^{-t}\,dt \leq \frac{1}{n!}e^{-n}\int^{n+1}_n t^n \,dt = \frac{1}{(n+1)!}e^{-n}\left((n+1)^{n+1}-n^{n+1} \right)
\end{align}
Using Stirling's asymptotics for the factorial we get:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}e^{-n}\left((n+1)^{n+1}-n^{n+1} \right) &=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{-n}\left((n+1)^{n+1}-n^{n+1} \right)}{\sqrt[]{2\pi (n+1)}(n+1)^{n+1}e^{-(n+1)}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e}{\sqrt[]{2\pi(n+1)}}\left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1} \right)^{n+1} \right)\\
&= 0
\end{align}
Using the squeeze theorem we get:
\begin{align}\tag{2}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\int^{n+1}_n t^n e^{-t}\,dt =0
\end{align} 
Putting (1) and (2) together gives the stated result, namely:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\int^n_0 t^ne^{-t}\,dt = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\int^{n+1}_0 t^ne^{-t}\,dt - \frac{1}{n!}\int^{n+1}_n t^ne^{-t}\,dt = \frac{1}{2}-0 =\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

The same idea for proving
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{e^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n^k}{k!}=\frac{1}{2}\tag{A}$$
applies here, too. The argument of the limit in the LHS of $(A)$ is the probability that a Poisson random variable takes a value which is $\leq $ than its expected value. The argument of your limit is the probability that a random variable with a $\Gamma$ distribution takes a value which is $\leq$ than its expected value. By the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) both limits equal $\frac{1}{2}$.